# How to apply function to parameters when they meet given constraints?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Lets say we have a function

```
f: (A, A) => A
```

and we are given two optional values

```
val x: Option[A] = ...
val y: Option[A] = ...
```

Now we want to apply the function `f` to `x`,`y`. In case one of the parameters is `None`, we want to return `None`. In scalaz we could write

```
^(x, y)(f)
```

Now assume that we want to restrict the input parameters for function `f` by coming up with another function which checks if the parameters meet a constraint. If so the function applies `f` to its arguments and returns the result wrapped in a `Some` object. Otherwise it returns `None`:

```
fRestricted: (A, A) => Option[A]
```

The problem now is that we cannot make use of Scalaz anymore, i.e.

```
^(x, y)(fRestricted)
```

does not work anymore, since the types are wrong.

Is this actually a common problem? Is there a generic solution for the use case?

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the most basic problems in functional programming (not just Scala).

The thing you were doing with Scalaz was based on applicative functor capabilities of the `Option`. Unfortunately the standard Scala library does not support applicative functors, however it does support monads, and `Option` is also a monad. Applicative functors are strictly a more general thing than monads, so whatever applicative functors can do, monads can do too.

Here's how you can exploit the fact that `Option` is a monad to solve your problem with the standard library:

```
for {
  a <- x
  b <- y
  c <- fRestricted(a, b)
} 
yield c
```

The syntax above is called a "for-comprehension", and in fact it is nothing more than just a sugar for the following:

```
x.flatMap( a => y.flatMap( b => fRestricted(a, b) ) )
```

Comment: You might want to add an example of how to use `fRestricted`, since that's what actually requires the monad instance?

Comment: Sure. Looks like I misinterpreted the question or the OP edited it in the first 5 minutes.